# incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds equality constraints: capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven, gson

I am trying to connect to run a query to fetch all the records in MongoDB and then convert the records into a list ofthe reference object type I am taking as a generic to my calling class. The code is running fine and achieving the desired result in Eclipse but gives a compilation error during a maven build , both maven and eclipse are referencing the same JDK(1.8). can someone please help me resolve this issue

```
public class MongoPersistenceImpl<T> {

MongoDatabase database=(MongoDatabase)MongoConnectImpl.getInstance().getConnection();

 public List<T> getAll(T modelObject){
        MongoCollection<Document> collection=database.getCollection(MongoConnectImpl.MONGO_COLLECTION);
        List<T> reportList=new ArrayList<>();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
               T report=gson.fromJson(cursor.next().toJson(),modelObject.getClass());
               reportList.add(report);
            }
            return reportList;
        }catch(Exception e){
            CatsLogger.printLogs(3, "30016", e, MongoPersistenceImpl.class,new Object[]{"get all"} );
            return null;
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Logs :-

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object
    upper bounds: T,java.lang.Object
```

The complete message on reproducing the same being :-

[image]

***UPDATE***: explicitly type casting the an Object variable worked , but I still need to understand how?

```
  public List<T> getAll(T modelObject){
        MongoCollection<Document> collection=database.getCollection(MongoConnectImpl.MONGO_COLLECTION);

        List<T> reportList=new ArrayList<T>();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
               Object rep=gson.fromJson(cursor.next().toJson(),modelObject.getClass());
               T report=(T)rep;//explicit type cast
               reportList.add(report);
            }
            return reportList;
        }catch(Exception e){
            CatsLogger.printLogs(3, "30016", e, MongoPersistenceImpl.class,new Object[]{"get all"} );
            return null;
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the Mave build _javac_ is used, whereas the Eclipse IDE uses its own compiler to incremental compile Java code. The error message of _javac_ is not very informative (e. g. there is no `capture#1` in your code). Are you sure the code is caused by the code snippet? Could you also show the code where `MongoPersistenceImpl<T>` is used?

Comment: @howlger the error had line numbers in it which pointed to `T report=gson.fromJson(cursor.next().toJson(),modelObject.getClass());` as the line with the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are trying to cast an object to a specific `Type` of `report`, try changing

```
T report = gson.fromJson(cursor.next().toJson(), modelObject.getClass());
```

to

```
T report = gson.fromJson(cursor.next().toJson(), (java.lang.reflect.Type) modelObject.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. it worked.. can you please elaborate on what the exact problem is?

Comment: The problem is the type you are trying to cast a class is unknown. When you cast it to `Type` you provide a superinterface to any type in Java which T can be in your definition of generics.

Comment: aah.. ok.. that's why explicitly type casting the Object afterwards is working.. thanks :)

Comment: @SakshamB Hope that helped :)

Comment: No [bounded type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) are involved here. The error message `inference variable T has incompatible bounds` doesn't make any sense to me.